# Java Swing JFrame minimize/maximize resize bug

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, maximize-window

The problem is that when I try to maximize the JFrame the frame does get maximized, but the content size is preserved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKSKF.png

My main frame class:

```
private CardLayout layout;

private SettingsFrame settingsFrame;

private Container contentPane;
Frame frame = this;

private ApplicationFrame() {       
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    layout = new CardLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(layout);
    initializeFrame();
    settingsFrame = new SettingsFrame(model);
    initializeMenuBar();
    initializePanels();                
    showPage(FIRST_PAGE);
    this.addWindowStateListener(listener);
}

public SettingsFrame getSettingsFrame() {
    return settingsFrame;
}

private void initializeFrame() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle(APPLICATION_TITLE);
    this.settingsFrame = new SettingsFrame(model);
    this.setSize(1400, 900);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    

private void initializePanels() {
    add(new Panel(), FIRST_PAGE);
    add(new Panel(), SECOND_PAGE);
    add(new Panel(), THIRD_PAGE);
}
```

I tried to make a listener, catch the maximize event and there i tried:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

also

```
invalidate();
validate();
```

but with no succes.

I found out that:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

is corectly maximizing the Frame, but i cannot use that is the listener because the maximize event already happened.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which unfortunately won't allow you to resize the `JComponent`. Because the `CardLayout` can hold/manage one or more components that share the same display space.
You should add a `JPanel` and set that panel's layout to the `CardLayout` if you wish to use it.

I strongly recommend reading the following documentation: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: (1+) Yes, the default layout manager for the content pane of a JFrame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the " CENTER" of the BorderLayout, the component will get all the space available to the frame. So leave the layout of the content pane alone and add a panel using a CardLayout to the content pane of the frame.